# Probability of an absolute value

Tags: probability

I'm currently studying normal approximation, and I came across the following example in a book, where alpha is a distribution parameter:

> $P(|\alpha| > .5) = P(-.5 < \alpha < .5)$

Why are these equivalent statements? I would have thought it would be:

> $P(|\alpha| > .5) = P(-.5 < \alpha) + P(\alpha > .5)$

Comment: Consider giving a [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, they are not equivalent. Perhaps they meant $1-\Pr(-0.5\le \alpha\le 0.5)$.

But your expression is not correct either. We want $\Pr(\alpha\lt -0.5)+\Pr(\alpha\gt 0.5)$.

Comment: right! thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome.